# Uniform continuity and interchange of limits

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$. If $f$ is compactly supported, then it is easy to check that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \int |f(x+h) - f(x)| = 0 $$
Is the statement true when $f$ is not compactly supported or when $f$ is not integrable? All integration is done in the Lebesgue sense.

Comment: Have you forgotten the absolute value? Otherwise transformation formula

Comment: I put the abs in. What's the transformation formula?

Comment: the previous integral was $0$ for any $h$.

Comment: What? That's just not true, take the indicator function of the set $[0,1]$

Comment: the previous integral, without absolute value. It does. Just compute the integral...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as $f$ is integrable, the statement is true. Compactly supported uniformly continuous functions are dense in $L^1(\mathbb R)$, so the result extends.

When $f$ is not integrable, the statement is not true. Take $f(x)=x$. Then $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int |f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)|\,dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int\epsilon\,dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\infty=\infty$.